# Python3.5 ImportError: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, importerror

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 64-bit. I downloaded Python3.5.1 Gzipped tarball source from https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-351/.

Then installed using

```
./configure
sudo make install
```

Then I upgrade pip by

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

it upgraded pip to 8.1.2, which is the latest version.
Then installed matplotlib package using

```
sudo pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

Now, when I import matplotlib into python, I get

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Jun  9 2016, 14:37:08) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 29, in <module>
import matplotlib.colorbar
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 32, in <module>
import matplotlib.artist as martist
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 14, in <module>
from .transforms import (Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/transforms.py", line 39, in <module>
from matplotlib._path import (affine_transform, count_bboxes_overlapping_bbox,
ImportError: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Please advise on how to fix this?

Comment: Example location of libpython3.5m.so.1.0 in an Ubuntu package : `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so.1.0`  http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpython3.5/filelist  ... i.e. may not be found in /usr/local/[hidden-location] , unless you point to it. -

Comment: I just went to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/, libpython3.5m.so.1.0 is not there

Answer (score 0):

Most people installed matlibplot through `Anaconda` or `Canopy` instead of installing it as an individual module. Usually if you have an error from `_path`, it means something wrong with your installation or compilation. `_path` is related to compiled c extentions. You can read the [installation](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html#building-on-windows) page of `matlibplot`. But the easiest way to fix it is to install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and you won't worry about a lot of things. Good luck!

Comment: I am aware of Anaconda but I am trying to use tensorflow0.9 which is not yet a conda package, I installed tensorflow0.9 using pip and I can't seem to use it with Anaconda. Hence, I installed Python3 and matplotlib individually, so I can use tensorflow with them.

Comment: Ok, so I didn't realize that there is Pip included inside Anaconda as well... so I installed tensorflow0.9 using instructions https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation but also add --ignore-installed with pip command and it works with anaconda now... so I guess I don't have to worry about these import errors anymore

Comment: Yes. This [page](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/pkgs.html) will help you to manage packages in Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue.  It's because my libpython binaries were installed to /usr/local/lib/ and the program was looking for libpython under /usr/lib/.  Making a symbolic link in /usr/lib/ solved the problem:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0 /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
```

or, in your case,

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpython3.5m.so.1.0 /usr/lib/libpython3.5m.so.1.0
```